# Eclipse and Mylyn : how to disable grey files in the explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse, mylyn

I have recently discovered Mylyn : it is a terrific Eclipse feature ! Very handy.
However, when working on a task, is there a way to disable grey files in the explorer ?

My typical Eclipse coding sessions with Mylyn look like this :

[image: package explorer]

All this grey color make the file names difficult to read, because of the lower contrast. When I must find a new file in the explorer (it happens very often), I have to screw up my eyes to be able to read the names... I can't stand it !

Is there a way to disable this grey color ?
I've searched in the Eclipse options and on Google, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gray color indicates that resource has lesser interest in context of a given task. You can disable this decorator from  workbench preferences / General / Appearange / Label Decorators / Task Context Decorator.