# Un-gray grayed out files in Eclipse Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse

Similar to [Eclipse and Mylyn : how to disable grey files in the explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056844/eclipse-and-mylyn-how-to-disable-grey-files-in-the-explorer)

My status is I've unchecked "Task Context Decorators" and I've uninstalled Mylyn via removing its packages from /plugins and /features (I've never even used it for tasks before).

How do I relieve this abyssal ailment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out!

Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Git

IT WAS GIT, and the grayed out files/folders were mostly "Uncommitted Changes", while the rest were "Ignored Resources". I just changed their colors.